# Can we solve $\frac{dx}{dt} = 3x+3t$ by "multiplying by $dt$"?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, alternative-proof

In preparation for ODE, I was just doing some practice problems when I came across this.

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = 3x+3t$$

Although I looked at the solution where it states to do an integration factor, is there anything inherently wrong with simply multiplying dt on both sides and then taking the integral of both sides and then isolating $x$? I would appreciate any clarity on this matter. Thanks so much.

Comment: How to integrate the unknown function  $x$ w.r.t. $t$ ?

Comment: The problem with multiplying both sides with $dt$ is that you would get; $$dx=3xdt+3tdt$$ What do you plan on doing with the $3xdt$ term?

Comment: @KurtG Thanks so much for the clarification. I forgot that x is not a variable, but rather a function. Thanks so much.

Comment: @Volk thanks so much for the clarification. Stated the same to KurtG. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> $dx/dt = 3x+3t$

No, you can't isolate them, because if you multiply $dt$ on both sides and integrate, then you get:

$$\int dx=\int 3xdt+\int3tdt$$

How do you deal with the first term on the RHS?

What you can do is either use the integration factor method, or to use substitution, let $u=x+t$, then we have

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{du}{dt}-1$$
the new differential equation becomes:

$$\frac{du}{dt}-1=3u$$
Now, you can separate them and integrate:

$$\int \frac{du}{3u+1}=\int dt$$

Can you proceed from here?

Answer (score 4):

This is a linear ordinary differential equation to written as
$$\frac{dx}{dt}-3x=3t$$
its integrating factor is $e^{\int -3 dt}=e^{-3t}$, then
$$x=e^{3t}\int e^{-3t} 3t dt+C e^{3t}$$

The other way is to assume $x+t=v \implies \frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{dv}{dt}-1$,
then you get
$$\frac{dv}{dt}=3v+1 \implies \int \frac{dv}{3v+1}=\int dt +C$$

Answer (score -6):

You need to separate the variables, a technique that you probably will learn in the ODE course. To do that, first subtract $3x$ from both sides and then multiply both sides by $dt$ yielding:$$-3x dx=3t dt$$Now you integrate both sides, taking the antiderivatives, you get:$$\frac{-3x^2}{2}=\frac{3t^2}{2}+C$$Simplifying, we get:$$C-x^2=t^2$$Can you finish it from here?

Comment: What you got here is obviously not a solution to that ODE.

Comment: how do you get the equation in  the first line?